# Local Storage to XML Template

Tags: javascript, html, xml, browser, local-storage

As the title says, I have in my browser on the **Local Storage** this:
movieTitle = ["Title1,Genre1, Director1, Year1", "Title2,Genre2, Director2, Year2"]
Can I retrieve back that array, and transform it into a **pre-defined** template on xml:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<club>
   <movie>
       <title>Title1</titol>
       <genre>Genre1</genre>
       <director>Director1</director>
       <year>Year1</year>
   </movie>
   <movie>
       <title>Title2</titol>
       <genre>Genre2</genre>
       <director>Director2</director>
       <year>Year2</year>
   </movie>


</club>
```

My JS Code to add elements to the Local Storage:

```
    function addTodo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const userInputHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('userAdd');
        const userInput = [].map.call(userInputHTMLCollection, element => element.value);
        const userListItem = document.createElement("li");
        userListItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userInput));
        list.appendChild(userListItem);
        const myArray = map(listItems, getText);
        localStorage.setItem('pelis_guardades', JSON.stringify(myArray));
    }
```

**Any way to keep adding what's on the local Storage onto that XML Template?**

PS: 
**How could later, when everythings added, download the XML File with the data?**

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: @Vepthy Yes, I want to parse from local Storage into XML